# Accessing Data from cloud firestore using flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

How can I access the "actual" data field from the 0th index **(just 0th index not other indexes)** of data['seniornotice'] in cloud firestore database using flutter?
Please see the image below

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.

```
Future<String> getActual() async {
 var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("seniornotice").doc("0YLOLYXxp2xFVFm4GuAt").get();
 return data["actual"];
}
```

### Edit

To assign the value, try  this.

```
String a;
void assign() async{
  a = await getActual();
}
```

Comment: can anything else be written instead of they auto generated key?

Comment: I don't get you @NazmulHayat. Are you referring to the document id?

Comment: yess i am referring to it

Comment: Like is it possible to use the indexes 
for example 
var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("seniornotice")[0].get();

Comment: Yes but you must have pushed it as "0","1","2","3"...
Note that documentID can't be an integer.

Comment: ok got it thank you

Comment: Kindly accept if this answers your question, @NazmulHayat.

Comment: when I print(getActual())why does it prints Instance of 'Future<String>'

Comment: Because it is a Future. If you want to print the value try
`getActual.then((actual) => print(actual));`

Comment: String s;
getActual().then((actual) => s = actual);

why is it printing null? @Locked

Like how shall I assign that value to a new variable instead of printing?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add document id in collection
Like this`FirebaseFirestore.instance.Collection(seniornotice/documentname)`